# How to encrypt photos on server/hide them from admin?

Tags: encryption, server

my idea was to create a site where photos can securely be uploaded and viewed by logged in users. There are many options (CMS, etc.) for this. What makes me feel uneasy is that many webhosts create automatic backups of files and then the unencrypted photos will be in there. It is not that I don't trust the admins but is there any way that uploaded files are encrypted so that only logged in users can see them? Thanks for helping.

Comment: Only possible when you decrypt these in your browser. So maybe googling client-side decryption might be the way too go. (This will be some work and your specification is quite incomplete/informal).

Comment: Store photos as data in a database. Encode to base64 (or encrypted in your case).  Done.

Comment: Better ask on https://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Aaron Far more complex measures are required to achieve securely encrypted photos server side. Client side encryption and decryption is required through a key derived from the users password, at the very least.

Comment: @LukePark I didn't say the encryption would be easy, but that's the direction he needs to take if he's thinking about storing them in a folder on the server somewhere. Nowhere in there did I mention the difficulty level or requirements for the encryption.  Comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Aaron It isn't the encryption that is difficult, it's the whole system design.  Your comment makes it sound like its a walk in the park, (especially the "Done" part) which is just not the case.  Implementing something like this takes a large amount of planning and I felt like your comment understated this fact.

Comment: @LukePark my apologies if you took my comment in a way I didn't mean it. I understood the OP to be asking about storing images as .pngs or .bmps or whatever in a folder system on the server - I wasn't trying to give him a full blown answer, I was trying to point him in a different direction. I'm sorry I said Done.

Comment: @Aaron No worries, I'm not taking personal offence or anything, I just don't want anyone to come past and read it and it be like "yep, easy!" and then proceed to implement an incredibly insecure system.  I'm merely campaigning for the greater good!

Comment: @LukePark I get it, my apologies once again. In my head, I was pointing him to a new way of doing things, that required starting from scratch... not something answered in 1 question. Like, go research this. And then ask 15 questions about the various things that come up.. But I also see your point.